# Hibernate: How to annotate two foreign keys as a composite primary key in the same entity

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I have two tables (articles and articles_partlist) in my db. 
The first table is for articles comprising of price, weight, ... and the partlist if the article is a composite article.
The second table is for the associated partlist of an article and consists of the reference article, the amount, ... and the single articles.
For the composite primary key I have an extra class.

**The two questions are now**: 
1.) How to annotate the two parts of the primary key, so that they are also two foreign keys? (composite primary key = two foreign keys)
2.) And how to map theese two foreign keys to the two OneToMany associations (referenceArticle and partlistArticle) in the article class?

The ArticlePartlist Class:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name="article_partlist")
public class ArticlePartlistElement {

@Column(name="count")
private long count;

@Column(name="show")
private boolean show;

@Column(name="single_prize")
private BigDecimal price;

@EmbeddedId
private ArticlePartlistElementId articleId;

// getters & setters
```

The ArticlePartlistId Class for the composite primary key:

```
@Embeddable
public class ArticlePartlistElementId implements Serializable {

@Column(name="article_id")
protected Article referenceArticle;

@Column(name="article_id_part")
protected Article partlistArticle;

// getters & setters & equals & hashCode
```

The Article class:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name="article")
public class Article extends AbstractMultiLanguageContainer<ArticleLanguage> {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name="art_num")
private String articleNum;

@Column(name="matchcode")
private String matchcode;

@Column(name="ean13")
private String ean13;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="vat_id")
private VatRate vatRate;

@Column(name="prize")
private BigDecimal price;

@Column(name="internal_remarks")
private String internalRemarks;

@Column(name="weight")
private Long weight;

@OneToMany (mappedBy="article")
@OrderBy("id asc")
private List<ArticleLanguage> articleLanguageDescriptions = null;

@OneToMany (mappedBy="articleId.referenceArticle")  
private List<ArticlePartlistElement> referenceArticle = null;

@OneToMany (mappedBy="articleId.partlistArticle")   
private List<ArticlePartlistElement> partlistArticle = null;

// getters & setters
```

Well, it's obvious that this is not working because the foreign key mapping is faulty. The articleId variable (in class articlePartlist) has to be from the type Article for a correct foreign key mapping.

Therefore I tried out to skip the ArticlePartlistId class and change the ArticlePartlist class to:

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name="article_partlist")
public class ArticlePartlistElement implements Serializable {

@Column(name="count")
private long count;

@Column(name="show")
private boolean show;

@Column(name="single_prize")
private BigDecimal price;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="article_id")
private Article referenceArticle;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="article_id_part")
private Article partlistArticle;

// getters & setters & equals & hashCode
```

This version might work, I got no error.